# Timeout in polling result file: error when starting Google Dataflow SQL query

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am new to Google Dataflow & Apache Beam. I am trying to deploy a dataflow job through Dataflow SQL. The job takes input from pubsub and writes to bigquery.

When I start a job using Dataflow SQL, I am getting error - Timeout in polling result file. 
This error comes for both gcloud CLI and also through Google Cloud Console.

Below is the snippet of the error.

```
2020-05-16 21:46:50.193 ISTTimeout in polling result file: gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-XXXXXXXXXXX/staging/template_launches/2020-05-16_09_06_52-11619869258908426171/operaton_result. Possible causes are: 1. Your launch takes too long time to finish. Please check the logs on stackdriver. 2. Service account XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com may not have enough permissions to pull container image gcr.io/dataflow-sql-templates/dataflow-sql-launcher-templates/dataflow_sql_launcher_image:20200303-rc00 or create new objects in gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/staging/template_launches/2020-05-16_09_06_52-11619869258908426171/operaton_result. 3. Transient errors occurred, please try again.
```

I guess the reason mentioned in this log cannot be true, because few times I was able to deploy the job successfully.

For successful cases the parameters between SELECT and FROM in the dataflow SQL query was less than 10. With the number of parameters between SELECT and FROM increased to 18 this problem is arising.

Below is a sample query I am using

```
        SELECT MIN(sensor.event_date) as day,
            MIN(sensor.event_timestamp) as event_timestamp,
            TUMBLE_START("INTERVAL 1 MINUTE") as parameters_timestamp,  
            sensor.sensor_id as sensor_id,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param2 AS FLOAT64)) as param2,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param3 AS FLOAT64)) as param3,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param4 AS FLOAT64)) as param4,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param5 AS FLOAT64)) as param5,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param6 AS FLOAT64)) as param6,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param7 AS FLOAT64)) as param7,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param8 AS FLOAT64)) as param8,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param9 AS FLOAT64)) as param9,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param10 AS FLOAT64)) as param10,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param11 AS FLOAT64)) as param11,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param12 AS FLOAT64)) as param12,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param13 AS FLOAT64)) as param13,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param14 AS FLOAT64)) as param14,
            AVG(CAST(sensor.param15 AS FLOAT64)) as param15
    FROM pubsub.topic.`project1`.`table1` AS sensor
    GROUP BY
      sensor.sensor_id,
      TUMBLE(sensor.event_timestamp, "INTERVAL 1 MINUTE")
```

When the error happens I found there is no console logs (i.e 2020-05-16_09_06_52-11619869258908426171/operaton_result) present in the Storage path. 
gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-XXXXXXXXXXX/staging/template_launches/

Thanks,
Jagan

Also here is the image with Job logs.
[Job Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGLHT.png)

Comment: You mentioned that you ran this job successfully previously. Did you change anything in the job?

Comment: I suggest contacting Google Cloud support. It's hard to debug this without looking into details about the job execution. I saw that some of the other users got similar errors since the container image was built incorrectly so pls make sure that you follow the steps correctly: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam_sql

Comment: @rmesteves Yes, I increased the number of parameters between SELECT and  FROM  in the dataflow SQL query to 18.  I now reduced parameter numbers to 9. After this reduction, I am able to start the dataflow SQL job.  Is there a limit in the number of parameters I can put in the SELECT Query.?

Comment: @chamikara I guess the issue is in the number of parameters or expression in QUERY SELECT. I observe with 9 or less than 9 expression, I am able to deploy the job. With 10 or more expression, the job template itself is not getting launched. Is there any limit in the number of expression in the SELECT Dataflow SQL Query.

Comment: @JaganKumarG I cant see anything related to limitations in the documentation. Can you share your query or part of it?

Comment: @rmesteves Updated the question with a sample Query, I am using.

Comment: Are you sure that all the parameters exist in your PubSub data? What is the size of the data?

Comment: yes, I am  publishing a json payload to PubSub.  The size of the data published is around 500 Bytes.

Comment: I'd like to try reproducing your issue. Can you provide a piece of your data or o model of the data you are publishing?

Comment: @rmesteves difficult to share the exact data published in the public forum. Please share any email id through which I can provide more details.  Actually I am able to start the required dataflow job using beam python sdk.

Comment: Check if you're using the right service account